# Why is Start running twice in this setup

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a completely new project with the following scripts attached to an empty GameObject:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Parent : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        print(">>>>>>>>>>>>> S T A R T <<<<<<<<<<<<<");
    }
}
```

and:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Child : Parent
{

}
```

Here is the result:

```
[07.07.55] >>>>>>>>>>>>> S T A R T <<<<<<<<<<<<<
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
[07.07.55] >>>>>>>>>>>>> S T A R T <<<<<<<<<<<<<
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
```

Why is Start executing twice in this setup?

Comment: Isn't this what you would expect?  For instance what if start was virtual and the child did something different.

Comment: Is this the correct behaviour you mean?

Comment: Yes.  Or, in other words, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Well I haven't used this very often but my expectation. is that the Child-script is an extension of parent inheriting fields, properties and functions in Parent from there. I somewhat understand your "virtual" comment but still puzzled that it should execute two times.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to answer it. But, when you write _"with the following scripts attached"_, it sounds like you have attached both `Parent` and `Child` to the `GameObject`. I.e. there are _two_ scripts attached. Is that correct? If so, then that completely explains the behavior. The class declaration is not itself the instance. It's just the definition of the code. But when you attach a `Parent`, you get a `Parent` instance and when you attached a `Child`, you get a `Child` instance. Both instances will call `print()`, hence the repeated output.

Comment: If you've attached two different scripts, and you are still having trouble comprehending the behavior, then it's probably premature for you to dive into Unity3d. You should learn more about object-oriented programming in general first, so that you have a firm grasp on concepts like inheritance and instantiation, and especially how those are two distinctly different features for an OOP language.

Comment: I just figured that out my self after testing. My mistake. It's like you do not see the forrest for all threes. Please post an answer and I will mark it as answer. BIG thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since the given situation is super simple, there are some possibilities, I think.

1. Actually, there are two gameobjects attatched with given script.
2. You attatched each `Parent` and `Child` component seperately.

...both are not very recommended way to use unity.

When designing a `MonoBehaviour`-inheriting class which maybe inherited by other class, it's often to declare Unity event function with `virtual` keyword, like:

```cs
public class Parent : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(">>>>>>>>>>>>> S T A R T <<<<<<<<<<<<<");
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        Debug.Log("This is Child!");
    }
}
```

And with gameobject attatched with `Child`, the console will write

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>> S T A R T <<<<<<<<<<<<<
This is Child!
```

But with `Parent` component, it will write only

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>> S T A R T <<<<<<<<<<<<<
```